# Gorilla Sessions Does Not Persist in Golang

Tags: session, go, gorilla

I'm having trouble with persisting the sessions in Golang using the Gorilla session handler. Similar issues (unresolved!) have been brought up in other stack overflow questions (here: [Sessions variables in golang not saved while using gorilla sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865681/sessions-variables-in-golang-not-saved-while-using-gorilla-sessions) and here: [cannot get gorilla session value by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237806/cannot-get-gorilla-session-value-by-key)). This is very scary, as it seems that 1) it is not just me 2) there does not seem to be a solution that currently exists 3) the Gorilla Sessions package may be fundamentally broken.

Here is the problem in more detail:

I can set sessions no problem when logging in. However, after I am logged in and I make another request to the backend the sessions values are not persisted, meaning that I cannot pull sessions.Value['username'] for example (even though that is the point of sessions).

So:

A) Log in, write sessions, retrieve session.Value['usernames'] and it works fine.

B) Navigate to another page on the front end and make another request to the backend (make a new character).

C) Attempt to retrieve session.Value['username']. It's nil!!!!

Here is the flow the user navigates on the backend to log in -

First here is the session handler:

```
package config

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

type Options struct {
    Path     string
    Domain   string
    MaxAge   int
    Secure   bool
    HttpOnly bool
}

type Session struct {
    ID      string
    Values  map[interface{}]interface{}
    Options *Options
    IsNew   bool
}

type Store interface {
    Get(r *http.Request, name string) (*sessions.Session, error)
    New(r *http.Request, name string) (*sessions.Session, error)
    Save(r *http.Request, w http.ResponseWriter, s *sessions.Session) error
}

var SessionsStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))

func init() {
    SessionsStore.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Domain:   "localhost",
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   3600 * 8, // 8 hours
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
}

func KeyStore() (store Store) {

    log.Print("inside KeyStore")
    store = SessionsStore
    log.Print("Value of store is : ", store)
    return store
}
```

Next, here is how I get from main to the routing to each of my components:

Main

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/config"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 5432
    user     = "patientplatypus"
    password = "superdupersecretyo"
    dbname   = "dungeon_world"
)

func main() {

    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        "localhost", 5432, "patientplatypus", "supersecret", "dungeon_world")
    var err error
    config.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = config.DB.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected~!")

    router := NewRouter()
    os.Setenv("ORIGIN_ALLOWED", "*")
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{os.Getenv("ORIGIN_ALLOWED")})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))

}
```

Here is the routing package that routes to each handler:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/users"

    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/dungeon_db"

    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/character"

    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/createcharacter"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(route.HandlerFunc)
    }

    return router
}

var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "ClassType",
        "POST",
        "/character/class",
        character.ClassType,
    },
    <MORE ROUTES FOLLOWING SAME PATTERN>
}
```

Now here is the login function. This is where I wrote the original session and printed out session.Values['username'] to show that it works:

```
package users

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/config"
)

type LoginResponse struct {
    Status string
}

type User struct {
    Username string
    Password string
    Id       int
}

func UserLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)

    var incomingjson User
    err := decoder.Decode(&incomingjson)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    username := incomingjson.Username
    password := incomingjson.Password

    log.Print("username: ", username)
    log.Print("password: ", password)
    if username != "" && password != "" {
        incomingjson.Login(w, r)
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "error username or password is blank!")
    }
}

func (incomingjson *User) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := config.KeyStore().Get(r, "cookie-name")
    log.Print("loginjson: ", incomingjson)
    var tempvar string

    err := config.DB.QueryRow("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=$1;", incomingjson.Username).Scan(&tempvar)
    log.Print("err: ", err)
    if err == nil {
        // 1 row
        log.Print("Found username")
        var passwordindatabase string
        config.DB.QueryRow("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=$1;", &incomingjson.Username).Scan(&passwordindatabase)
        if passwordindatabase == incomingjson.Password {
            log.Print("username and password match!")
            session.Values["authenticated"] = true
            session.Values["username"] = incomingjson.Username
            config.KeyStore().Save(r, w, session)
            response := LoginResponse{Status: "Success, user logged in"}
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
        } else {
            log.Print("username and password don't match!")
            session.Values["authenticated"] = false
            session.Values["username"] = ""
            config.KeyStore().Save(r, w, session)
            response := LoginResponse{Status: "Failure, username and password don't match"}
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
        }
    } else {
        //empty result or error
        log.Print("Username not found or there was an error: ", err)
        response := LoginResponse{Status: "User not found!"}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
    }
}
```

Now here is the problem component. It's job is to make a new character after checking that the user exists (sessioncheck is ok)...

So here I have:

```
package createcharacter

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/config"
)

var Username string
var Checkok bool


func SessionsCheck(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (username string, checkok bool) {
    store := config.KeyStore()
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "cookie-name")
    log.Print("inside sessionscheck...what is the value of stuff....")
    log.Print("session: ", session)
    log.Print("session.Values: ", session.Values)
    log.Print("username: ", session.Values["username"])
    log.Print("authenticated: ", session.Values["authenticated"])
    if session.Values["username"] == nil {
        if session.Values["authenticated"] == false {
            log.Print("Verboten!")
            http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
            return "nil", false
        }
    }
    return session.Values["username"].(string), true
}

func NewCharacter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    Username, Checkok = SessionsCheck(w, r)
    <FUNCTION CONTINUES>
```

This is where I am getting the error...but I don't know how to fix.

The terminal output is :

```
2017/10/15 15:08:56 inside KeyStore
2017/10/15 15:08:56 Value of store is : &{[0xc42010c000] 0xc42007d5f0}
2017/10/15 15:08:56 inside sessionscheck...what is the value of stuff....
2017/10/15 15:08:56 session: &{ map[] 0xc4201316b0 true 0xc4200e0a80 cookie-name}
2017/10/15 15:08:56 session.Values: map[]
2017/10/15 15:08:56 username: <nil>
2017/10/15 15:08:56 authenticated: <nil>
2017/10/15 15:08:56 http: panic serving [::1]:53668: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not string
goroutine 13 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc42015c5a0)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1697 +0xd0
panic(0x133bcc0, 0xc420061f00)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0x283
github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/createcharacter.SessionsCheck(0x1540d00, 0xc42010a540, 0xc42014ea00, 0xc42011ab00, 0x3, 0xc420001680)
    /Users/patientplatypus/Documents/golang/src/github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/createcharacter/charactercontroller.go:31 +0x5c9
github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/createcharacter.NewCharacter(0x1540d00, 0xc42010a540, 0xc42014ea00)
    /Users/patientplatypus/Documents/golang/src/github.com/patientplatypus/gorest/createcharacter/charactercontroller.go:35 +0x5a
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x13b8690, 0x1540d00, 0xc42010a540, 0xc42014ea00)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1918 +0x44
github.com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP(0xc420066360, 0x1540d00, 0xc42010a540, 0xc42014ea00)
    /Users/patientplatypus/Documents/golang/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:133 +0xed
github.com/gorilla/handlers.(*cors).ServeHTTP(0xc42010c7e0, 0x1540d00, 0xc42010a540, 0xc42014e800)
    /Users/patientplatypus/Documents/golang/src/github.com/gorilla/handlers/cors.go:118 +0x5c8
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc42014a000, 0x1540d00, 0xc42010a540, 0xc42014e800)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2619 +0xb4
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc42015c5a0, 0x1541240, 0xc420061dc0)
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x71d
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/src/net/http/server.go:2720 +0x288
```

I am sorry for the verbosity, but I think this is the most minimal example I can reproduce from my code base. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

EDIT:

One thing that I have noticed is the following:

```
2017/10/15 15:08:56 session: &{ map[] 0xc4201316b0 true 0xc4200e0a80 cookie-name}
2017/10/15 15:08:56 session.Values: map[]
```

Seems to indicate that the username and authenticated (true 0xc4200e0a80) are being stored *outside* of the session.Values []map function. Why is that?

EDIT EDIT:

So...I thought that the way that I wrote config.KeyStore() may have been an issue so I rewrote it to the following and the persisted it throughout the project:

```
package config

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

var SessionsStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("secret"))

func init() {
    SessionsStore.Options = &sessions.Options{
        Domain:   "localhost",
        Path:     "/",
        MaxAge:   3600 * 8, // 8 hours
        HttpOnly: true,
    }
}
```

So now wherever I need SessionsStore I just call conf.SessionsStore. That's seemingly as canonical a way to do it as I think is possible. I still have the same issue.

Comment: Be careful: you are ignoring the error returned by CookieStore::Get - Get always returns a non-nil session, but also the error might be not null (like in the case of a newly created session).

Comment: So I just checked that. err there is nil, but I really think the problem is that sessions arent mapped correctly (see my EDIT). I don't know how to fix this if thats the issue.

Comment: I reviewed the sample code that Gorilla provides (I don't use sessions as I think that they are a fundamentally bad idea, and JWT provides a stateless mechanism for user authentication), however the code seems very different from yours. Would you mind giving a go to the documentation? He seems to use completely different methods...

https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/sessions

Comment: I've looked at the code. I don't see how it is different than what I am using currently. Can you point out any differences that you see that may break my code in a full comment @AlessandroSantini?

Comment: @PeterWeyand As a note, you shouldn't use 2 queries to authenticate the user in the DB, you can select the username and password on the same query and avoid an unnecessary query, or even better `select user where user = $1 and password = $2` and then the DB makes the check for you at the same time it looks for your row.

Comment: Writing a few lines of code to test if the session works correctly. BRB.

Comment: @PeterWeyand I'm pretty sure the issue is on how the cookies are being saved. Can you post the values for the cookies shown in the browser when the cookie just got set, and on the page where the request is failing? Also FWI I downvoted the question because you are ignoring errors in 2 places in your example, and I want to help and everything but I can't be sure you are not just ignoring a stupid error and making as all loose our time. NEVER ignore the errors.

Comment: @PeterWeyand Could you show us the information about the cookies? Because I have used gorila sessions in my code and they work and I think the issue has something to do with how they are being saved on the browser.

Comment: ... @Topo..... I already have it's written in the question ...

Comment: @PeterWeyand Sorry about that. That's the issue there, when working on localhost the domain on the cookie should be "" instead of localhost. ;)

Comment: @Topo - no that is not the problem. It did not fix the issue, I get the same error.

Comment: @PeterWeyand Try without setting the domain parameter at all, or with the domain set to 127.0.0.1 Also, which browser are you using? I think setting the cookie domain to 127.0.0.1 only works on firefox.

Comment: @Topo I have tried setting Domain: "localhost:<PORTNUMBER>" and commenting out Domain in the options. Neither option works. I am skeptical that this is the source of the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156786/discussion-between-topo-and-peter-weyand).

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

const appCookie = "myappcookies"

var cookies *sessions.CookieStore

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //
    // For the sake of simplicity, I am using a global here. 
    // You should be using a context.Context instead!
    session, err := cookies.Get(r, appCookie)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    session.Values["userName"] = "StackOverflow"
    session.Save(r, w)
}

func Session(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, err := cookies.Get(r, appCookie)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Objects in session: %d\n", len(session.Values))))
    for k, v := range session.Values {
        w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("Key=%v, Value=%v\n", k, v)))
    }
}

func main() {
    cookies = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("mysuperdupersecret"))
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.Path("/login").Methods(http.MethodPost).HandlerFunc(Login)
    router.Path("/session").Methods(http.MethodGet).HandlerFunc(Session)
    server := &http.Server{
        Handler: router,
        Addr:    ":8000",
        // Good practice: enforce timeouts for servers you create!
        WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
        ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

Comment: This is tested working but, as you can see, my API calls to the sessions API are completely different from yours.

Comment: This looks very much like what I have. the only difference seems to be that I put things in different files and make cookies a global variable. See my EDIT EDIT above.

Comment: Yes, I did miss the EDIT EDIT as I was in Atom :) the number of files is not really the issue, though. Gorilla Sessions works, there must be something wrong in the flow of your application. It's hard to replicate your environment locally.

Comment: I think it IS an issue. It means that there are problems holding Sessions cookies as a global variable. And if I don't do that that means that all my functions must be in a single file (which is impossible as I poll cookies throughout the project). This is not a solution that generalizes!!!

Comment: Peter, I am sorry but several files get compiled into a single binary that runs in a single process. No, what you just said is downright incorrect.

Comment: I cannot generalize your answer to how sessions should be handled globally across more than one file. I don't see how I can take what you've done and generalize to multiple files. That is a correct statement.

Comment: Peter, I tried to break the system into three different files and it works flawlessly. https://file.io/O6Szms https://file.io/OUUgLu https://file.io/5Arl86 . I suggest you try a little harder. Not working on this question anymore.